# Create custom result source in share point Online or Office 365 Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, search, office365, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have to create custom result source in share point Online or Office 365 for more than 100 sites. I need to write power shell script for this activity.In most of the blogs or articles its written about only  On premises versions.I need PS Script for SP Online or Office 365. Please share the  links of any existing articles for SP Online or any code snippet for office 365 would be helpful.

Thanks
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

To use SPO, you need to setup your environment. This stuff is all over the web.

TechNet provides this information, YouTube and many sites dedicated to this, all of O365/Azure really. You just have to search for it.

Using your favorite search engine, 'SharePoint Online PowerShell'

Example hit:

Windows PowerShell for SharePoint Online reference
Provides links to categorized Windows PowerShell cmdlets that you can use in SharePoint Online.
The following articles list Windows PowerShell cmdlets for SharePoint Online by functionality:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161397.aspx

Youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+sharepoint+online

MS PowerShell Gallery
https://www.powershellgallery.com/items?q=sharepoint+online&x=0&y=0